# JDBC . can the database be exported with the jar file?

Tags: java, jdbc

Recently, I constructed a java application that uses `JDBC` in order to connect to `mysql`. The question is this: if I export the java application as a jar file, does the database itself gets exported with the jar file? In other words, can the application still connect to the database (`mysql`) on any pc?

Comment: do know the steps to connect to Database through java?

Comment: No. `JDBC` is an interface to the database, not the database itself.

Comment: If the database is running on a remote server, and the client can connect to that server, and you've given the client the proper URL and credentials, and the database allows connections from that client machine with those credentials, then the application can connect to the database.  If not, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) is an API that defines how a client interacts with the database, it's a separate thing.